# run a function in python as non blocking thread

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am simulating a use case in which clients send a request to the server for a particular service time and then, the server  creates a new VM for each client request and then  stop VM and destroy VM  when service time is over. For simulating this behavior, I have made a client request generator which sends the requests to the server as a tuple of type at a certain arrival rate

> [client id, arrival_time_of_request ,service time, type of VM]

[image]

In my opinion, the server should run these 3 modules in working in parallel shown as `thread 1`, `thread 2` and `thread 3` in above figure

1. **Pool manager**: it is responsible for parsing client request and calling 
   various other modules as shown in the diagram as separate threads
2. **start VM:** for starting a VM and calling service time manager for each when each VM is started.
3. **stop VM:** for stopping a  VM destroying it when service time is over
4. **service time manager:** It will decrement the service time for all the clients per second.  I am using the `sleep(1)` in a `for loop for all clients` which is decrementing the time for each client and calling `stop VM` when service time for a particular client is over.

Now the issue is that I don't know how to run these 3 modules in parallel thread function in a different process which is non-blocking as it contains the sleep time. As for each request, when a VM is started, then a request should be sent to service time manager, so when the `service time manager` has sleep then the whole program closes.

Comment: Parallel run, Impossible! You cannot run parallel, but you can match using common data. When I set up similar sentences on this platform, I'm being judged mercilessly. The time intervals contain infinite elements and each element is **unique** and cannot be synchronized  (see Perception resolution). Parallel and synchronous words are a big lie. As for your question, all your processes create a data and compare that data in another process and create a result.**You can not synchronize the eternities.**